# Pandas - How to convert multiarray (3D) into understandable dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I got this kind of format but can't perform df.head()

```
data = pd.read_pickle(r'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\GitHub\555967_1012435_bundle_archive\data.txt')
data

[array([[[108, 108,  74],
         [113, 113,  79],
         [108, 108,  74],
         ...,
         [176, 179, 188],
         [175, 178, 187],
         [172, 175, 184]],
 
        [[104, 104,  70],
         [111, 111,  77],
         [107, 107,  73],
         ...,
         [176, 179, 188],
         [175, 178, 187],
         [172, 175, 184]],
 
        [[ 91,  91,  57],
         [104, 104,  70],
         [103, 103,  69],

df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
df
```

error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5354fc045452> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
      2 df

c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    339                 records.extend(recs)
    340 
--> 341     _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
    342 
    343     result = DataFrame(records)

c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level)
    308                         seen_meta[key] = _pull_field(obj, val[-1])
    309 
--> 310                 _recursive_extract(obj[path[0]], path[1:], seen_meta, level=level + 1)
    311         else:
    312             for obj in data:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I'm using from this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/imrul273/realdataset40k

Comment: what is the result after df.head()

Comment: Of course an error message

Comment: `df` is a `list` not a `DataFrame` . `df[0]` is an `array` which is (x,y,3) where x and y are probably the number of pixels and 3 is for red, green, blue color. You can work with data in this format, or convert into a dataframe if needed

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is your using `pd.read_pickle()` for a case where the data was not saved as a "pickled" python object. In this case, you most likely want `pd.read_csv()`

Just make sure to set your `delimiter` argumant correctly

Comment: Have you checked the dataset? Its binary